# Blocking <select> when checbox is selected horizontally

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a problem with carrying out a certain command.

After clicking on the checkbox, I want it to lock the  fields horizontally.

I need the code to execute the command, after clicking on the "checkbox" it will block the hour checkbox.

I already tried If (), but it doesn't work as it should, locking me in all the fields, not just the ones I should. Can You help me?

```js
$('body').on('change input', '.from-opening, .to-opening, .status-check', function() {
  var licGroupObj = {};
  licGroupObj = $('.license_group').map(function(idx, ele) {
    var dayWeek = $(ele).find('.from-opening').data('days');
    var hOpen = $(ele).find('.from-opening').val();
    var hClosed = $(ele).find('.to-opening').val();

    if ($(ele).find('.status-check:checked').val()) {
      var status = 'closed';
    } else {
      var status = 'open';
    }

    return {
      dayWeek,
      hOpen,
      hClosed,
      status
    };
  }).get();

  $('#opening_hours').val('');
  $('#opening_hours').val(JSON.stringify(licGroupObj));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group row license_group">
  <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Poniedziałek</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <select name="openingHours" class="form-control from-opening" data-days="poniedziałek">
      <option value="00:00">00:00</option>
      <option value="00:30">00:30</option>
      <option value="01:00">01:00</option>
      <option value="01:30">01:30</option>
      <option value="02:00">02:00</option>
      <option value="03:30">03:30</option>
      <option value="04:00">04:00</option>
      <option value="04:30">04:30</option>
      <option value="05:00">05:00</option>
      <option value="05:30">05:30</option>
      <option value="06:00">06:00</option>
      <option value="06:30">06:30</option>
      <option value="07:00">07:00</option>
      <option value="07:30">07:30</option>
      <option value="08:00">08:00</option>
      <option value="08:30">08:30</option>
      <option value="09:00">09:00</option>
      <option value="09:30">09:30</option>
      <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
      <option value="10:30">10:30</option>
      <option value="11:00">11:00</option>
      <option value="11:30">11:30</option>
      <option value="12:00">12:00</option>
      <option value="12:30">12:30</option>
      <option value="13:00">13:00</option>
      <option value="13:30">13:30</option>
      <option value="14:00">14:00</option>
      <option value="14:30">14:30</option>
      <option value="15:00">15:00</option>
      <option value="15:30">15:30</option>
      <option value="16:00">16:00</option>
      <option value="16:30">16:30</option>
      <option value="17:00">17:00</option>
      <option value="17:30">17:30</option>
      <option value="18:00">18:00</option>
      <option value="18:30">18:30</option>
      <option value="19:00">19:00</option>
      <option value="19:30">19:30</option>
      <option value="20:00">20:00</option>
      <option value="20:30">20:30</option>
      <option value="21:00">21:00</option>
      <option value="21:30">21:30</option>
      <option value="22:00">22:00</option>
      <option value="22:30">22:30</option>
      <option value="23:00">23:00</option>
      <option value="23:30">23:30</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <select name="openinHours" class="form-control to-opening">
      <option value="00:00">00:00</option>
      <option value="00:30">00:30</option>
      <option value="01:00">01:00</option>
      <option value="01:30">01:30</option>
      <option value="02:00">02:00</option>
      <option value="03:30">03:30</option>
      <option value="04:00">04:00</option>
      <option value="04:30">04:30</option>
      <option value="05:00">05:00</option>
      <option value="05:30">05:30</option>
      <option value="06:00">06:00</option>
      <option value="06:30">06:30</option>
      <option value="07:00">07:00</option>
      <option value="07:30">07:30</option>
      <option value="08:00">08:00</option>
      <option value="08:30">08:30</option>
      <option value="09:00">09:00</option>
      <option value="09:30">09:30</option>
      <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
      <option value="10:30">10:30</option>
      <option value="11:00">11:00</option>
      <option value="11:30">11:30</option>
      <option value="12:00">12:00</option>
      <option value="12:30">12:30</option>
      <option value="13:00">13:00</option>
      <option value="13:30">13:30</option>
      <option value="14:00">14:00</option>
      <option value="14:30">14:30</option>
      <option value="15:00">15:00</option>
      <option value="15:30">15:30</option>
      <option value="16:00">16:00</option>
      <option value="16:30">16:30</option>
      <option value="17:00">17:00</option>
      <option value="17:30">17:30</option>
      <option value="18:00">18:00</option>
      <option value="18:30">18:30</option>
      <option value="19:00">19:00</option>
      <option value="19:30">19:30</option>
      <option value="20:00">20:00</option>
      <option value="20:30">20:30</option>
      <option value="21:00">21:00</option>
      <option value="21:30">21:30</option>
      <option value="22:00">22:00</option>
      <option value="22:30">22:30</option>
      <option value="23:00">23:00</option>
      <option value="23:30">23:30</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input status-check" type="checkbox">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckChecked">
                Zamknięte?
              </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row license_group">
  <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Wtorek</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <select name="openinHours" class="form-control from-opening" data-days="wtorek">
      <option value="00:00">00:00</option>
      <option value="00:30">00:30</option>
      <option value="01:00">01:00</option>
      <option value="01:30">01:30</option>
      <option value="02:00">02:00</option>
      <option value="03:30">03:30</option>
      <option value="04:00">04:00</option>
      <option value="04:30">04:30</option>
      <option value="05:00">05:00</option>
      <option value="05:30">05:30</option>
      <option value="06:00">06:00</option>
      <option value="06:30">06:30</option>
      <option value="07:00">07:00</option>
      <option value="07:30">07:30</option>
      <option value="08:00">08:00</option>
      <option value="08:30">08:30</option>
      <option value="09:00">09:00</option>
      <option value="09:30">09:30</option>
      <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
      <option value="10:30">10:30</option>
      <option value="11:00">11:00</option>
      <option value="11:30">11:30</option>
      <option value="12:00">12:00</option>
      <option value="12:30">12:30</option>
      <option value="13:00">13:00</option>
      <option value="13:30">13:30</option>
      <option value="14:00">14:00</option>
      <option value="14:30">14:30</option>
      <option value="15:00">15:00</option>
      <option value="15:30">15:30</option>
      <option value="16:00">16:00</option>
      <option value="16:30">16:30</option>
      <option value="17:00">17:00</option>
      <option value="17:30">17:30</option>
      <option value="18:00">18:00</option>
      <option value="18:30">18:30</option>
      <option value="19:00">19:00</option>
      <option value="19:30">19:30</option>
      <option value="20:00">20:00</option>
      <option value="20:30">20:30</option>
      <option value="21:00">21:00</option>
      <option value="21:30">21:30</option>
      <option value="22:00">22:00</option>
      <option value="22:30">22:30</option>
      <option value="23:00">23:00</option>
      <option value="23:30">23:30</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <select name="openinHours" class="form-control to-opening">
      <option value="00:00">00:00</option>
      <option value="00:30">00:30</option>
      <option value="01:00">01:00</option>
      <option value="01:30">01:30</option>
      <option value="02:00">02:00</option>
      <option value="03:30">03:30</option>
      <option value="04:00">04:00</option>
      <option value="04:30">04:30</option>
      <option value="05:00">05:00</option>
      <option value="05:30">05:30</option>
      <option value="06:00">06:00</option>
      <option value="06:30">06:30</option>
      <option value="07:00">07:00</option>
      <option value="07:30">07:30</option>
      <option value="08:00">08:00</option>
      <option value="08:30">08:30</option>
      <option value="09:00">09:00</option>
      <option value="09:30">09:30</option>
      <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
      <option value="10:30">10:30</option>
      <option value="11:00">11:00</option>
      <option value="11:30">11:30</option>
      <option value="12:00">12:00</option>
      <option value="12:30">12:30</option>
      <option value="13:00">13:00</option>
      <option value="13:30">13:30</option>
      <option value="14:00">14:00</option>
      <option value="14:30">14:30</option>
      <option value="15:00">15:00</option>
      <option value="15:30">15:30</option>
      <option value="16:00">16:00</option>
      <option value="16:30">16:30</option>
      <option value="17:00">17:00</option>
      <option value="17:30">17:30</option>
      <option value="18:00">18:00</option>
      <option value="18:30">18:30</option>
      <option value="19:00">19:00</option>
      <option value="19:30">19:30</option>
      <option value="20:00">20:00</option>
      <option value="20:30">20:30</option>
      <option value="21:00">21:00</option>
      <option value="21:30">21:30</option>
      <option value="22:00">22:00</option>
      <option value="22:30">22:30</option>
      <option value="23:00">23:00</option>
      <option value="23:30">23:30</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input status-check" type="checkbox">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckChecked">
                Zamknięte?
              </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="opening_hours" id="opening_hours" value="">
```

Comment: What do you mean by "lock"?

Comment: By clicking the "Zamknięte?" checkbox, it blocks two fields <select>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go:

```js
$('body').on('change input', '.from-opening, .to-opening, .status-check', function() {
  var licGroupObj = {};
  licGroupObj = $('.license_group').map(function(idx, ele) {
    var dayWeek = $(ele).find('.from-opening').data('days'),
        hOpen = $(ele).find('.from-opening').val(),
        hClosed = $(ele).find('.to-opening').val(),
        status = false

    if(ele.querySelector('.status-check').checked) status = true

    if(status) ele.querySelectorAll('select').forEach(e => e.disabled = true)
    else ele.querySelectorAll('select').forEach(e => e.disabled = false)

    console.log(
      dayWeek,
      hOpen,
      hClosed,
      status
    )

    return {
      dayWeek,
      hOpen,
      hClosed,
      status
    };
  }).get();

  $('#opening_hours').val('');
  $('#opening_hours').val(JSON.stringify(licGroupObj));
})
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group row license_group">
  <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Poniedziałek</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <select name="openingHours" class="form-control from-opening" data-days="poniedziałek">
      <option value="00:00">00:00</option>
      <option value="00:30">00:30</option>
      <option value="01:00">01:00</option>
      <option value="01:30">01:30</option>
      <option value="02:00">02:00</option>
      <option value="03:30">03:30</option>
      <option value="04:00">04:00</option>
      <option value="04:30">04:30</option>
      <option value="05:00">05:00</option>
      <option value="05:30">05:30</option>
      <option value="06:00">06:00</option>
      <option value="06:30">06:30</option>
      <option value="07:00">07:00</option>
      <option value="07:30">07:30</option>
      <option value="08:00">08:00</option>
      <option value="08:30">08:30</option>
      <option value="09:00">09:00</option>
      <option value="09:30">09:30</option>
      <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
      <option value="10:30">10:30</option>
      <option value="11:00">11:00</option>
      <option value="11:30">11:30</option>
      <option value="12:00">12:00</option>
      <option value="12:30">12:30</option>
      <option value="13:00">13:00</option>
      <option value="13:30">13:30</option>
      <option value="14:00">14:00</option>
      <option value="14:30">14:30</option>
      <option value="15:00">15:00</option>
      <option value="15:30">15:30</option>
      <option value="16:00">16:00</option>
      <option value="16:30">16:30</option>
      <option value="17:00">17:00</option>
      <option value="17:30">17:30</option>
      <option value="18:00">18:00</option>
      <option value="18:30">18:30</option>
      <option value="19:00">19:00</option>
      <option value="19:30">19:30</option>
      <option value="20:00">20:00</option>
      <option value="20:30">20:30</option>
      <option value="21:00">21:00</option>
      <option value="21:30">21:30</option>
      <option value="22:00">22:00</option>
      <option value="22:30">22:30</option>
      <option value="23:00">23:00</option>
      <option value="23:30">23:30</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <select name="openinHours" class="form-control to-opening">
      <option value="00:00">00:00</option>
      <option value="00:30">00:30</option>
      <option value="01:00">01:00</option>
      <option value="01:30">01:30</option>
      <option value="02:00">02:00</option>
      <option value="03:30">03:30</option>
      <option value="04:00">04:00</option>
      <option value="04:30">04:30</option>
      <option value="05:00">05:00</option>
      <option value="05:30">05:30</option>
      <option value="06:00">06:00</option>
      <option value="06:30">06:30</option>
      <option value="07:00">07:00</option>
      <option value="07:30">07:30</option>
      <option value="08:00">08:00</option>
      <option value="08:30">08:30</option>
      <option value="09:00">09:00</option>
      <option value="09:30">09:30</option>
      <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
      <option value="10:30">10:30</option>
      <option value="11:00">11:00</option>
      <option value="11:30">11:30</option>
      <option value="12:00">12:00</option>
      <option value="12:30">12:30</option>
      <option value="13:00">13:00</option>
      <option value="13:30">13:30</option>
      <option value="14:00">14:00</option>
      <option value="14:30">14:30</option>
      <option value="15:00">15:00</option>
      <option value="15:30">15:30</option>
      <option value="16:00">16:00</option>
      <option value="16:30">16:30</option>
      <option value="17:00">17:00</option>
      <option value="17:30">17:30</option>
      <option value="18:00">18:00</option>
      <option value="18:30">18:30</option>
      <option value="19:00">19:00</option>
      <option value="19:30">19:30</option>
      <option value="20:00">20:00</option>
      <option value="20:30">20:30</option>
      <option value="21:00">21:00</option>
      <option value="21:30">21:30</option>
      <option value="22:00">22:00</option>
      <option value="22:30">22:30</option>
      <option value="23:00">23:00</option>
      <option value="23:30">23:30</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input status-check" type="checkbox">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckChecked">
                Zamknięte?
              </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row license_group">
  <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Wtorek</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <select name="openinHours" class="form-control from-opening" data-days="wtorek">
      <option value="00:00">00:00</option>
      <option value="00:30">00:30</option>
      <option value="01:00">01:00</option>
      <option value="01:30">01:30</option>
      <option value="02:00">02:00</option>
      <option value="03:30">03:30</option>
      <option value="04:00">04:00</option>
      <option value="04:30">04:30</option>
      <option value="05:00">05:00</option>
      <option value="05:30">05:30</option>
      <option value="06:00">06:00</option>
      <option value="06:30">06:30</option>
      <option value="07:00">07:00</option>
      <option value="07:30">07:30</option>
      <option value="08:00">08:00</option>
      <option value="08:30">08:30</option>
      <option value="09:00">09:00</option>
      <option value="09:30">09:30</option>
      <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
      <option value="10:30">10:30</option>
      <option value="11:00">11:00</option>
      <option value="11:30">11:30</option>
      <option value="12:00">12:00</option>
      <option value="12:30">12:30</option>
      <option value="13:00">13:00</option>
      <option value="13:30">13:30</option>
      <option value="14:00">14:00</option>
      <option value="14:30">14:30</option>
      <option value="15:00">15:00</option>
      <option value="15:30">15:30</option>
      <option value="16:00">16:00</option>
      <option value="16:30">16:30</option>
      <option value="17:00">17:00</option>
      <option value="17:30">17:30</option>
      <option value="18:00">18:00</option>
      <option value="18:30">18:30</option>
      <option value="19:00">19:00</option>
      <option value="19:30">19:30</option>
      <option value="20:00">20:00</option>
      <option value="20:30">20:30</option>
      <option value="21:00">21:00</option>
      <option value="21:30">21:30</option>
      <option value="22:00">22:00</option>
      <option value="22:30">22:30</option>
      <option value="23:00">23:00</option>
      <option value="23:30">23:30</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <select name="openinHours" class="form-control to-opening">
      <option value="00:00">00:00</option>
      <option value="00:30">00:30</option>
      <option value="01:00">01:00</option>
      <option value="01:30">01:30</option>
      <option value="02:00">02:00</option>
      <option value="03:30">03:30</option>
      <option value="04:00">04:00</option>
      <option value="04:30">04:30</option>
      <option value="05:00">05:00</option>
      <option value="05:30">05:30</option>
      <option value="06:00">06:00</option>
      <option value="06:30">06:30</option>
      <option value="07:00">07:00</option>
      <option value="07:30">07:30</option>
      <option value="08:00">08:00</option>
      <option value="08:30">08:30</option>
      <option value="09:00">09:00</option>
      <option value="09:30">09:30</option>
      <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
      <option value="10:30">10:30</option>
      <option value="11:00">11:00</option>
      <option value="11:30">11:30</option>
      <option value="12:00">12:00</option>
      <option value="12:30">12:30</option>
      <option value="13:00">13:00</option>
      <option value="13:30">13:30</option>
      <option value="14:00">14:00</option>
      <option value="14:30">14:30</option>
      <option value="15:00">15:00</option>
      <option value="15:30">15:30</option>
      <option value="16:00">16:00</option>
      <option value="16:30">16:30</option>
      <option value="17:00">17:00</option>
      <option value="17:30">17:30</option>
      <option value="18:00">18:00</option>
      <option value="18:30">18:30</option>
      <option value="19:00">19:00</option>
      <option value="19:30">19:30</option>
      <option value="20:00">20:00</option>
      <option value="20:30">20:30</option>
      <option value="21:00">21:00</option>
      <option value="21:30">21:30</option>
      <option value="22:00">22:00</option>
      <option value="22:30">22:30</option>
      <option value="23:00">23:00</option>
      <option value="23:30">23:30</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input status-check" type="checkbox">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckChecked">
                Zamknięte?
              </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Used some pure js here, also added console log to you see the result and of course added `flex` to body to make better visibility.